# AsyncTask cannot update progress when slowly creating an object in background

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I know how to use `AsyncTask` to download file, create a zip file or so.. as I call `publishProgress()` in my loop.
I got stuck when `doInBackground()` has a single slow line, no loops here, just creating an object where its constructor has slow loops.

I'm not sure about the reasonable way of updating progress in such case.

Here's a sample code:

```
public class Session {
   private QQActivity activity;
   public int createdParts;
   public DailyClass daily;

   private void checkDaily() {
     if(!isDailyReady){
      new SetAsyncQQDaily().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
     }
   }
   class SetAsyncQQDaily extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String sdq = null;
            daily = new DailyClass(Session.this); //Very very Slow!
            // Do other network http
            sdq = new String(Base64.encode(bos.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT));
            // Do some work
            return sdq;
     }      

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String sdq) {
       //Never mind
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
       Toast.makeText(activity,"Preparing the daily. Get ready!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
       //TODO: Update Value of leftBar
       activity.leftBar.setProgress((100*createdParts)/Utils.DAILY_PART_COUNT);
     }
  }
}
```

In the slow constructor class, I can set-back an integer of the current progress: `createdParts`, but cannot call `publishProgress`.

```
public class DailyClass implements Serializable {
public DailyClass(Session session){
    for(int i=1;i<=partCount;i++ ){ //Very slow loop
        session.createdParts = i; //TODO: reflect value to progress bar!?
        for(int j=0;j<questionsCount;j++){
            objects[i-1][j] = createDefined(i);
        }
        Log.d("Daily","created part"+i);
    }
    }
    //Bla .. !
}
```

I also though of passing the object of the AsyncTask to the slow constructor in order to call `publishProgress()` from there, but cannot. As `publishProgress()` is accessible only from `doInBackground()`

What's the best practice?

Comment: publishProgress is accessable from every method of asynctask. So you could make a memberfunction which does just that. But you could also make DailyClass an inner class of your asynctask.

Comment: Thanks @greenapps, I have modified the constructor and passed the asyncTask. I added a public function that passes int argument to `publishProgress(i)`. But the progressBar does not get refreshed, no update, except when I flip the phone orientation. How can I force to refresh the UI. I read that setProgress() triggers repainting .. but that does not happen. I am not blocking the UI thread, as other components seem working fine .. Mmm... what do u think?

Comment: Only at orientation change? Hmmmm... Would you have created a new object of the task? Do away with the parameter and give your activity a variable which is the asynctask.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot understand your question. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: At further tought my idea does not hold. So sorry: at the moment I give up.